# iPhone music no longer synced with PC

Tags: music, ios, iphone, data-synchronization

My iPhone syncs with my PC. The music from my PC syncs - or rather, *did* - with my iPhone. It doesn't now.

Actions I took that probably caused this:

1. I transferred music from 3 CDs to my laptop
2. Deleted the music on my phone
3. Synced the phone with my laptop and got the music (copied from the CD to laptop) on my phone.
4. Attached iPhone to PC and synced. Apps and Outlook synch okay, but not the music. The music on my phone remains only as per the synch with the laptop.

Is there a way I can get the music from my PC (ticked choices in iTunes list) back onto my iPhone and keep the stuff already on it?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out some of the suggestions from [this Apple.SE question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/28153/10639). Basically, make the music libraries of your two computers (PC and laptop) available to your iPhone via either:

- **[iTunes Home Sharing](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3819)**
- **iCloud** (if your library isn't too large OR you don't mind paying)

[This article](http://macintoshhowto.com/audio/how-to-sync-and-share-your-itunes-music-across-multiple-mac-computers-and-iphones.html) also suggests **iTunes Match** as an option.

Another alternative is to merge the music libraries from your two computers:

- Copy the music from one machine to the other that your phone is currently syncing with
- Copy the music from your iPhone to a computer - see [this Lifehacker article](http://lifehacker.com/5869827/how-to-copy-music-from-your-iphone-ipad-or-ipod-touch-to-your-computer-for-free) for suggestions for several platforms (Windows, OS X, Linux)

Lastly, you can manually manage your music on the iPhone, which prevents a sync altogether and allows you to drop music in from multiple computers. This [Apple Support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1535?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) explains it in detail.